# How to mock AWS SDK Cognito Identity Provider service properly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I'm trying to write unit tests for the module which depends on `AWS.CognitoIdentityProviderService` from `'aws-sdk`'. I wanted to mock its methods and test if they are indeed called with `jest.expect.toHaveBeenCalled()` as

```
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('aws-sdk'),
  CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => ({
    adminGetUser: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getUser: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    adminDeleteUser: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    adminUpdateUserAttributes: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    associateSoftwareToken: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    adminSetUserMFAPreference: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    verifySoftwareToken: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    adminCreateUser: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    adminUserGlobalSignOut: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    promise: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true)),
  })),
}));

import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

But I tried as follows (didn't work):

```
expect(AWS.CognitoIdentityProviderService.prototype.adminGetUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params)
// Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function (received undefined)
```

then tried as follows (didn't work):

```
const mockCognitoIdentityProviderService = new AWS.CognitoIdentityProviderService() // after above mocking

const spy = jest.spyOn(mockCognitoIdentityProviderService, 'adminGetUser')
// call service here...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled() // doesn't call
```

I tried with `aws-sdk-mock` but that didn't work since my CognitoIdentityProviderService initialization is not in the class method I'm trying to test.

Comment: I would recommend _not_ mocking complex things you don't own. Push that behind a facade you do own, then test interactions with the real system at the integration/E2E level.